# GraphQL Custom scalar type DateScalar

Tags: mongodb, graphql, scalar

This is my Resolvers, typedefs and dateScalar file. I am in the process of creating a custom scalar Date to represent Date for an object when querying through GraphQL.

resolvers.js

```
const dateScalar = require("./dateScalar");
const resolvers = {

  DateScalar: {
    dateScalar,
  },
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

dateScalar.js

```
module.exports = {
DateScalar: new GraphQLScalarType({
name: "DateScalar",
description: "Date Scalar type",

parseValue(value) {
  return new Date(value);
},
parseLiteral(ast) {
  if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
    // return parseInt(ast.value, 10);
    return new Date(ast.value);
  }
  return null;
},
serialize(value) {
  // const date = new Date(value);
  // return date.toISOString();
  return value.getTime();
},
}),
};
```

typeDef.js

```
const {gql} = require("apollo-server-express);
const typeDefs = gql`
scalar DateScalar
type Item{
Date: DateScalar
 } `
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: When I query, The date comes back as following: "undefined NaNth, NaN at NaN:NaN am"

Answer (score -1):

This is literally [the example in the Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/). You have to pass the `dateScalar` directly to `DateScalar` and not pun the property:

```
const resolvers = {
  DateScalar: dateScalar,
};
```

Comment: When I query, The date comes back as following: "undefined NaNth, NaN at NaN:NaN am" –